# OpenCV object detection via cascade java (NOT FACE DETECTION)

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv, object-detection, cascade-filtering

dear friends, i use openCV in Java. Everything is fine but the thing is that am limited with API, i cant create C files (i'm not skilled in C/C++ that much and i did not use them for a long time) for my specific tasks, thus i must solve my problem with haar cascade xml file...

My task is to detect simple objects NOT FACEs, just simple objects like cup on the table, clock on the wall...

I think it is possible with edge detecting, but i did not find any cascades for this simple detection stuff. It is quite hard for me to google it because when i search object detection it always gives face detection stuff...

Could you please suggest me solution for this?
Your help will be appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: If you solved your problem, you can apply my webcam-interface and share your solution with my software? (if yes, please ask for latest interface) http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=6193&lngWId=10

Comment: Sure i'll help, please describe in more detail what you need, and how can i help you... (find me on skype "vochix") :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own haarcascades, but it's a lot of work!
You will find some interesting links in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000816/how-to-create-haar-cascade-xml-for-using-with-opencv).

As you said, there are other ways to detect objects, like edge detection or [color tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486386/detect-red-blobs-in-a-image-using-opencv) for instance. There are plenty of resources for this on the web.

Comment: I did not find what i was looking for, but thank you for response Simon :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i find the solution,

1) Solution one - there is very useful blob function witch does exactly what i wanted to, and even more, it detects center of the blob...

2) You can use deprecated method CV.findContours(...) and do your necessary stuff.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or fixes to this...