# FAST Feature Detector/Descriptor EMGUCV/OpenCV

Tags: .net, performance, opencv, emgucv

I am a newbie with this stuff so please bear with me :-)

I am creating a object **recognition** application which can Recognize objects. Frames are grabbed by a webcam and tracking and recognition is done in real-time.

I am a C#/VB.NET developer, and therefore I am using EmguCV OpenCV Wrapper.
I have tried SURF feature detector and it takes 5 seconds per frame!

Therefore I am trying to use FAST descriptor.

Can anybody give me sample code, say a function FAST(Byval modelImage, ByVal observedImage)
which will return the points of the object? Please. If not sample code please help me. The EMGUCV documentation is telling me nothing.

I appreciate your response. I am just a newbie. Please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/FAST_feature_detector_in_CSharp

Solves the problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

Hi once I worked on EMGUCV/OpenCV but i do not know if it will help you but to detect custom objects you would have to work on harrcascades. you should look at [How to create Harcascades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000816/how-to-create-haar-cascade-xml-for-using-with-opencv)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply but I am looking for something trainable within seconds. (Haar takes hours for an object) I actually wanted a sample code for FAST in Emgu. But Thanks :-)

Comment: neural network? do you have any idea how can I use neural networks? Thanks Alot!! I have used EIGENObjectRecognizer which works perfectly with faces as I can extract faces using HAAR. Eigen does not tell me the exact position :-(

Comment: Eigne vector depends on harcascades. My friend made such a project for his Masters Thesis that recognises the image on runtime without har cascades and then detects. He used some Neural Networks and Machine Learning.may be if i get in contact with him i can ask him:)