# face detection javacv android

Tags: android, face-detection, javacv

I'm trying to detect mouth in already detected face (detected face => detect mouth), the problem is that it detects eyes as if they are mouth! how do I solve this problem?

BTW I'm using  haarcascade_mouth.xml with CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING.
Please help me out.

Comment: I think you need to improve the AI algorithm, which isn't a few lines of code

Comment: how can I improve algorithm? can you please elaborate?

Comment: "if you can't explain something to a 6 years old child, than you even don't know it". - this is true, but I am not sure you know how is going the face, voice recognition algorithm, those are projects for who finish masters and write 80 pages of explanations what they did there. You can do it, try with google, allocate a few months for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best thing is to create your own haar cascades for mouths of all types and perspectives:

[How to create Haar Cascade (xml) for using with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000816/how-to-create-haar-cascade-xml-for-using-with-opencv)

Then you should apply all of them on your face and accumulate their output on the different regions of the face to decide which outputs overlap the most and fit a rectangle that is most likely the mouth. An even more elegant way of combining these simple classifiers would be boosting (which would require another training step):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_%28machine_learning%29

But if you are lazy - why not just putting constraints on the result of the output of the haarcascade_mouth? This would mean that you only accept outputs which are in the lower 50% of the image (y < sizeY/2) and/or only 10 % off center (x > 0.4*sizeX && x < 0.6*sizeX).

Comment: Is this answer sufficient or what do you need more?