# Extract correct contours in Laplacian Edge Images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation, vision

Staring with frames looking like this:
[image]

I am using BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 to detect motion in the frames and extract regions of interest where I use biliteral filter and equalizeHist and afterwords apply laplacian and threshhollding.

I get reasonable laplacian edges and noisy masks via threshholding after applieng different image filters like here:
[image]

however, I am not sure how I can now extract the correct contour of the object(left top) to segment it.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: instead of background subtraction you could try frame subtraction: thresh(abs(frame_n-1 - frame_n)) && thresh(abs(frame_n - frame_n+1)) typically gives good results for moving objects. If you combine it with a tracking you should be able to have the mouse even if it stays static.

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than it first seems. My solution would be train a network for this task. If you want to segment the mouse, you have to collect a few hundreds of pictures from different contexts. Maybe 100 could give you a satisfying result already. I would use transfer learning (this means using a network already trained with some other data). Using the following repository it's not so complicated: https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models
For data augmentation I would use imgaug:
https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

With a solution not using deep you could use texture analysis. I would use Gabor decomposition for this, you could probably see the difference between the texture of the background and the mouse. However a neural seems simpler and a more trendy technology to learn.

You should also consider to buy a new imaging device and/or an IR light projector, if that's why you have such a low contrast. Only the IR camera of a Raspberry PI you would get incredible images compared with those and your detection might work without any change.

Comment: yeah its just a project for university, so we should not use deep learning and also the data is given.

but thanks for the advice with texture analysis

Comment: Could you please add the topleft original image?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using opencv to train a Haar cascade to detect the mouse.

This is often used in face recognition/object recognition in video - it seems quite efficient.

You can see a helpful Q&A on how to do it here:

[How to create Haar Cascade (.xml file) to use in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000816/1021819)

As mentioned in the other answer, transfer learning is no longer onerous. You just need training data - which Haar will need too. Otherwise you will have to simulate it.

You could even think about templating the mouse

Comment: good idea, I will have a look at it if Gabor decomposition is not working